# How do I delete the current row from within the detail view of a UITableView app?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, storyboard, uitoolbar

I am developing a UITableView app in Swift using storyboards. My app has two view controllers: a MasterViewController and a DetailViewController.

I am trying to replicate the behavior of Apple's Notes app. In Apple's Notes app, when a user clicks on the Trash Bar Button item displayed within the Detail View, the application shows an Action Sheet with two options: "Delete Note" and "Cancel". If the user clicks on "Delete Note", the current contents of the Detail View fade out, the current row is deleted, and the contents of the next row fade in.

I added a toolbar with a Trash Bar Button item to the detail view. I am able to call a method of the DetailViewController when the user clicks on the Trash Bar Button and am able to display the Action Sheet. I have been unable to make the current contents of the view fade out and be replaced with the contents of the next row.

How do I do that?

Here is the code that populates the detail view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" { 
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() { 
           let object = objects[indexPath.row] as Note 
           println("setting detailItem! row: ", indexPath.row) 
           (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object 
           (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).delegate = self 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you add some relevant code . Especially your didSelecetRow method and the code that brings up the detail view ? Then we can work through this. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't have a didSelectRow method in the MasterViewController. However, the detail view is populated correctly and displays the values in the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You can go pretty straightforward way, creating a special setter in `DetailViewController`:

```
func setDetailItem(newItem: AnyObject, animated:Bool)
{
    if animated
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            <yourtextview>.alpha = 0.0
            },
            completion: {(finished:Bool) -> Void in
            self.detailItem = newItem
            <yourtextview>.alpha = 1.0   // back to visible state instantly

        })
    }
    else
    {
        self.detailItem = newItem
    }
}
```

then adding boolean flag in `MasterViewController` (for example, named `isDeletion`)and set it to `true` in remove button tap handler. And alter your `prepareForSegue` a bit:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" { 
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() { 
           let object = objects[indexPath.row] as Note 
           println("setting detailItem! row: ", indexPath.row) 
           // previous code
           //(segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object 
           // new code
           if isDeletion
           {
               isDeletion = false   // don't forget to clear the flag
               controller.setDetailItem(object, animated: true)
           }
           else
           {
               controller.setDetailItem(object, animated: false)
           }
           (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).delegate = self 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Now the text should fade out after delete and instantly change after plain selection.
Smells a bit Objective-C-ish, of course :)